# Making a 3d Menu in Director or Flash (with selection) possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript, 3d, lingo, adobe-director

I need to do a Director project with a 3D style menu (to clarify, it's a study manual with a human body with several parts to be selected, for example, to study arm muscles you need to click the arm).

I want to accomplish this with a 3D model, rather than using tricks (like pre rendered videos to look like a 3d model). Now the problem here is not the 3d model itself, but if its possible to do click events on different parts of the same model. Is it possible?

I'll need to use Director to do the project, but my boss warned that most likely would be possible to use a flash SWF as well and embue it in the director, thus working. Anyone with 3D experience can tell me if thats okay? (I don't need to know exactly HOW it works by this time, but if you could lead me to an example or tutorial, even better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes loading complex 3d models possible and quite easy with actionscript + some additional libraries. You can take a look papervision and away3d libraries. Here one nice example.

http://papervision2.com/away3d-tutorial-loading-complex-models-with-away3d/

Generally collada (xml based 3d models) best solution but if there is to much polygon then your swf will need time for loading on client side.
After this probably you will take a look how to load 3d models and convert with blender to collada and how to reduce polygons via blender.

Comment: And I assume clicking on several parts of the model can give me diferent events? (like say, click arm, go to frame 2 and click head go to frame 3?) I also need to pass those out to director, so I need some sort of comunication with outside apps (even if its just a string with some information of what was clicked), is that possible?

Comment: Yes I have done something similar, you create a transparrent button and place by x,y,z coordinates. Also I would like to inform you this solution just for flash+3d models. I was using cs3 while I was doing that. Maybe there is something more easier with directory->flash implementation.

Comment: Okay, thats helpfull. for now I just need to know if thats possible so my boss can tell the client if we can do the job or not. Thank you for your time. :)